# Eclipse Marker Resource does not exist

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

for my custom editor I want to add a marker, but got an exception.
The exception is
*Resource '/c/runtime-EclipseApplication/HelloWorld/hello.me' does not exist.*
But res is not null, any idea?

```java
   public static IPath getPathFromEditorInput(IEditorInput input) {
      if (input instanceof ILocationProvider)
         return ((ILocationProvider) input).getPath(input);

      if (input instanceof IURIEditorInput) {
         URI uri = ((IURIEditorInput) input).getURI();
         if (uri != null) {
            IPath path = URIUtil.toPath(uri);
            if (path != null)
               return path;
         }
      }

      return null;
   }

   @Override
   protected void editorSaved() {
      IPath path = getPathFromEditorInput(getEditorInput());
      try {
         createMarker(ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(path), 2);
      }
      catch (CoreException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      super.editorSaved();
   }

public static IMarker createMarker(IResource res, int line) throws CoreException {
      IMarker marker = null;
      // note: you use the id that is defined in your plugin.xml
      if (res != null) {
         marker = res.createMarker("com.mymarker");
         marker.setAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, 0);
         marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_START, 10);
         marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_END, 20);
         marker.setAttribute(IMarker.LOCATION, "Snake file");
         marker.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, "Syntax error");
      }
      return marker;

   }
```

Here is snippet from plugin.xml

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.core.resources.markers"  
            id="com.mymarker"  
            name="ME errors">  
        <super type="org.eclipse.core.resources.problemmarker" />  
        <super type="org.eclipse.core.resources.textmarker" />  
        <persistent value="true" />
    </extension>
```

Comment: Take a closer look at the path in the message. Is that a valid path under the workspace root?

Comment: `res` is not `null`, but I guess [`res.exists()`](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IResource.html#exists%28%29) will return `false`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(path)` requires a path which is relative to the workspace root, you are giving it an absolute file path.

Use `getFileForLocation` for a full path:

```java
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFileForLocation(path)
```

Also note that if the `IEditorInput` is an instance of `IFileEditorInput` then you can get the `IFile` using `IFileEditorInput.getFile()`